# Build Qt for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I searched the Web for few days now, for how to build `Qt 4.8.6` for `Visual Studio 2012`. I am using Windows 10 x64.

I tried following:

Enviroment Variables:

```
QTDIR=c:\Qt\4.8.6
Path=%QTDIR%\bin
QMAKESPEC=%QTDIR%\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012
```

Visual Studio Native Tools Command Prompt:

```
cd c:\Qt\4.8.6
nmake confclean
configure -no-webkit -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2012
jom -j 8
```

But I always get Error-Codes: (last few lines)

```
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DNDEBUG -I"..\..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\include" -I"..\..\..\include\ActiveQt" -I"tmp\moc\release_shared" -I"..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fotmp\obj\release_shared\ @C:\Users\HONIAH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.146576.5359.jom
moc_mainwindow.cpp
link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.6\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.6\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:release\undoframework.exe @C:\Users\HONIAH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\undoframework.exe.146576.7484.jom
jom: C:\Qt\4.8.6\Makefile [sub-examples-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Comment: You built Qt itself from the source code and wondering how to point to it from your project? And the error is very not clear.

Comment: No, I want to build the Source Code so I can use `Qt` with `Visual Studio`.
But I always get error-code 2 while building `Qt`.

Comment: No, you don't have to do that at all just for using Qt with Visual Studio. You can use prebuilt Qt. Moreover, without knowing this stuff you will not be able to use the Qt you build yourself with Visual Studio.

Comment: Using prebuild Qt does not work. I got `LNK1319-Error` and `LNK2038-Error` while building my program. On another computer with VS2005 compiling this program works fine.

Comment: I do that both ways. But it takes specific things to enable custom built with either Visual Studio or Qt Creator. I really doubt anyone can tell you what you do wrong. It takes a direct access to your PC.